# SUID bit in linux, not working as it should

Tags: linux, shell, setuid

I have a text file called *Demo*, which have write permission for the owner only.
I also have an executable file (here called *demowr.bash*) that will write to this *Demo* file, and because I want other users to use this program, I set the set-uid bit.
Here is what the `ls -l` is seen for the files.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 Coder Coder 6 Oct 28 23:36 ./Demo
-rwsrwxr-x 1 Coder Coder 7472 Oct 28 23:27 ./demowr.bash*
```

If I execute the file as Coder, all is fine.
But if I run it as any other user, it does not work, saying that it does not have write permission.

I have used the following codes to the executable file and the text file:

```
chmod u+s ./demowr.bash
chmod o-w ./demowr.bash

chmod o-w ./Demo
chmod g-w ./Demo
```

Here is the contents of the *demowr.bash* file

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1">Demo
```

Why is that,that even when the **s** bit is set, I am unable to write when run as an another user?

**PS**

> Linux ignores the setuid¹ bit on all interpreted executables (i.e.
>   executables starting with a #! line)

I also wrote a C program, to do the same thing. The result is the same, the `access` function is saying that write permission is not given. 
Here is the C code:

```
#define FILENAME "./Demo"

int main(int argn, char *argv[])
{
  int length = strlen(argv[1]);
  if (access(FILENAME,W_OK) == -1){
    printf("Error: You do now have write permission.\n");
    return 1;
  }

  int fd = open(FILENAME,O_WRONLY);
  write(fd,argv[1],length);
  close(fd);
  return 0;
}
```

When run as a non-owner, I am getting the error.

```
Error: You do now have write permission.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do my setuid root bash shell scripts not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565729/why-do-my-setuid-root-bash-shell-scripts-not-work)

Comment: I have edited my question. It is not a duplicate.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html "The check is done using the calling process's *real* UID and GID, rather than the effective IDs as is done when actually attempting an operation (e.g., [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)) on the file."

Comment: Also, your code is broken: Check the return value from `open` for errors before using `fd`.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved.

Comment: **WATCH OUT:** Having that program available as a setuid binary will allow anyone who can run it to gain root privileges.

Comment: For any value of `X`, _"X not working as it should"_ almost always means _"X not working **as I expected**"_ — the SUID bit is, in all probability, working as it should.