# Why the setuid program does not have the privilege to execute system()

Tags: linux, permissions, setuid

I have the following program:

```
$ cat cat.c
#include <err.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char buf[32];

  if(argc == 1) {
    errx(1, "please specify an argument.");
  }

  sprintf(buf, "cat %s", argv[1]);
  system(buf);
  return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc cat.c -o mycat
$ chmod +s mycat; sudo chown root mycat
$ ls -lth mycat
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root ... 11:12 mycat
$ ls -lth secret
-rw------- 1 root ... 11:10 secret
```

I thought `./mycat secret` should be able to read the secret file because mycat is a setuid program, and its owner is `root`. However, here is what I get:

```
$ ./mycat secret
cat: secret: Permission denied
$ sudo chown user1 secret
$ ./mycat secret
4ea6f17dd6818
```

Anything I misunderstood?

Comment: It does have the privilege to execute `system()`. It is `cat` that doesn't have the privilege to read `secret`. Read the error message.

Comment: @user207421 Permissions aren't associated with programs, they're associated with users and groups. Running setuid root should give it privilege to read the file.

Comment: The reason is that `/bin/sh` drops its setuid privileges.

Comment: This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565729/why-do-my-setuid-root-bash-shell-scripts-not-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program demonstrates what's working and what doesn't :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char buf[64];
  if (fork() == 0){
    char *newargv[] = { "cat", argv[1], NULL };
    execve("/usr/bin/cat", newargv, NULL); // This call directly `cat` without spawning a `shell`, so works as expected.
    return 0;
  }
  sprintf(buf, "cat %s", argv[1]);
  system(buf); // `system` spawns a shell which then calls `cat`, as the `shell` lost setuid privilaege, `cat` fails with `Permission denied`.
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I found if I execve("/bin/sh", ...); and use setuid to the program, the launched shell is not in root privileged. Is this because setuid cannot be applied to any shell-related programs?