# Postgresql cannot change to root with -u shortcut

Tags: linux, postgresql

Recently updated from Postgresql **9.1** to **9.3**.

Everything works fine, but I noticed now when I type in:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

I am getting hit with a *permission denied error* for changing dir to root.

> "Could not change directory to /home/root.

However, when I use:

```
sudo su - postgres 
psql
```

It accesses it fine. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
sudo -i -u postgres psql
```

This accomplishes (almost) the same thing as your

```
sudo su - postgres
```

The `-` in the above indicates that you want to use the postgres account's environment.  If you remove the `-`, it will fail similarly to `sudo -u`

The `-i` indicates that you want to run the postgres account's login shell (hence `cd`ing to their home directory).

Answer (score 23):

change directory to someplace that postgres has access to:

```
cd /tmp
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Comment: Why then does su work? It should have access to the dir, or I should get the same error, should I not?

Comment: I don't know.   I went through this post to figure it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598001/how-do-you-find-the-original-user-through-multiple-sudo-and-su-commands and i couldn't find a difference that made sense.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782366/postgresql-cannot-change-to-root-with-u-shortcut/45145825#45145825). `sudo su postgres` will give you similar errors.

Answer (score -1):

For me this did the trick (or you'll get a `could not change directory to "/root": Permission denied`), pay attention to quotes (')

```
sudo -Hiu postgres 'pg_dump --column-inserts --data-only --table=someTable entities_db > /var/backups/anywhere/$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)_someTable.sql'
```

Note the `-Hiu`for sudo, or use `su - postgres`

you can also put that in a cronjob for root with `crontab -e`