# Postgres can not change directory in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to create and use a new database in postgres.  When I try to load the db with the command below:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

I get this error.

> could not change directory to
>   "/home/laptop/Dropbox/js/hw/Has-Many-Relationships": Permission denied
>   psql (9.3.13) Type "help" for help.

I have tried to change the folder permissions in nautilus as root.  This command will work as expected when the folder is changed to root (cp and cd /)  Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql cannot change to root with -u shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782366/postgresql-cannot-change-to-root-with-u-shortcut)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It sounds like your shell's CWD (Current Working Directory) is

```
/home/laptop/Dropbox/js/hw/Has-Many-Relationships
```

and that the 'postgres' user does not have access to that directory.

However, by the next line, you DO seem to be able to talk to a running PostgreSQL server, though you don't share the next line.

This may be helpful if this is a "completely throwaway" database instance on your local machine (laptop):

http://johnmee.com/how-to-reinstall-postgresql-on-ubuntu

This method will completely purge all postgres packages (not just the virtual package) and allow you to start over with a fresh install of PostgreSQL.

Once you've got a clean install of PostgreSQL, try this, as root:

```
# cd ~postgres/
# sudo -u postgres psql
```

And see if the error does not repeat.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks!  It appears to be working.  Very odd that postgres is a user that has access but is unable to use that access.

Comment: w00t! Glad I could help. Just remember that you are running as the 'postgres' user, and that user will only have rights to write to it's own home directory. That error message isn't about a problem connecting to the database, per se, but a problem with the local CLI client, running as 'postgres' user, not having permissions to access the directory root could.

Comment: @JesseAdelman how would I allow the postgres user access to some folder in my home directory? I want to store the data on another harddisk via a symlink, so I think this is what I may need.

Comment: @stats-hb Well, that's a different question. :) Can you make this a real question? If I have time, I'll check on that question. Cheers.