# Get user while packaging rpm

Tags: linux, rpm, packaging, rpm-spec

I am trying to get USER-NAME in my spec file while packaging rpm. "$HOME" command gives me USER in case of running in bash.
Spec file also works like bash but when I run the similar command in %post section of spec file, I get 'root' as output.
This might be happening as user run rpm package using sudo.

Kindly help how to get USER name in Spec file

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598001/how-do-you-find-the-original-user-through-multiple-sudo-and-su-commands), it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `.spec` a `%define` macro would get you the username. Here is an example, how it might look like inside the `.spec` file.

```
 Source0: %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz

 # User defined function to get who built the RPM
 %define packagername %(who am i | awk '{print $1}')

 %description
 ...
 %prep
 ...

 # Then in the post section call the macro %{packagername}
 %post
 echo "Packager is: %{packagername}"
```

Note, `%post` section will be run only when install the `.rpm` file. Above will print the information into `stdout`.

Output

```
$ sudo rpm -ivh simple-0-1.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:simple                 ########################################### [100%]
Packager is:  iamauser
```

In order to use this macro globally on the system, one can define it inside `/etc/rpm/macros.<somename>`.

```
$ cat /etc/rpm/macros.username
# Get who is the packager
%packagername %(who am i | awk '{print $1}')
```

With the global definition one doesn't need to define it inside the `.spec` file.

If you don't have permission to write into `/etc/rpm`, then defining it in `~/.rpmmacros` file would make that macro available only to you.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am getting only username, however, I want to get the complete path of user (for e.g: /home/<user_name>). Btw sorry for late reply..