# Can I find which user used sudo to run my script?

Tags: bash

I have googling around for long time but couldn't actually find a reliable way.

This is what I want:

Use Bash script, check if user is actually root root, not the user with sudo command.

I have tried many ways , like `id -u`, `$EUID`, `whoami`, etc., but all of them return same value when run as root and using sudo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you find the original user through multiple sudo and su commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598001/how-do-you-find-the-original-user-through-multiple-sudo-and-su-commands)

Comment: What is the difference between "being `root`" and running a command *as* `root`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if there are some environment variables set by sudo:

```
set | grep SUDO
```

Output:

```
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/bash
SUDO_GID=1000
SUDO_UID=1000
SUDO_USER=user1
```