# How to get the loggin users from C when running under sudo

Tags: linux, sudo, glibc

I'm writing a C application that will be run under sudo.

I need to get the original logged in users UID.

I'm calling getuid which the documentation states will return the real UID.

I assumed this would be the logged in user's UID but it instead returns 0 which is the root UID.

Is there an api call which will allow me to get the logged in users UID.

I'm aware of SUDO_UID but would prefer to avoid environment variables (or am I just being difficult).

Comment: doubtful it is possible, since the orignal uid is not preserved, except well in the environment variable, cause sudo is nice and wants you to know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you find the original user through multiple sudo and su commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598001/how-do-you-find-the-original-user-through-multiple-sudo-and-su-commands)

Comment: The link you passed doesn't look like it provides reliable results which is critical for this application.

Comment: well if there were any reliable "other" ways, I think those would have been posted there, why do you think there would be new ways that will suddenly spring up here. Anyway Why are you avoiding environment variables anyway.

Comment: There may be another way, I'm no C expert but, my guess is that if you check what parent process ran `sudo` and get `uid` for that, you would be effectively getting the id of the user that ran sudo. Posting an answer with an example `hello_sudoer.c`, minimal example further checks have to be done to make it secure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution without using environment variables relying on `stat()` and files in `/proc/<pid>`, so this makes it linux only.
Basically it goes trough the process tree until it finds `(sudo)` or `pid=1`, if sudo is found it shows the parent process that called it and the uid for that.

`hello_sudoer.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
struct process_info {
    pid_t pid;  
    // max file name is 255 + 2 for "()" in /proc/<pid>/stat
    char process_name[257]; 
    char status;
    pid_t ppid; // parent process id
    uid_t uid; // uid of this process
};

struct process_info get_process_info(pid_t pid){
    struct process_info pi;
    struct stat* s = malloc(sizeof(struct stat));
    memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(struct process_info));
    if(pid > 0) {
        char proc_path[64];
        FILE* proc_stat;
        memset(&proc_path, 0, sizeof(proc_path));
        sprintf(proc_path , "/proc/%d/stat", pid);
        proc_stat = fopen(proc_path, "r");
        if (proc_stat != NULL) {
            fscanf(proc_stat, "%d %s %c %d", 
                    &pi.pid, 
                    pi.process_name, 
                    &pi.status, 
                    &pi.ppid);

            // stat struct doesn't have the parent process id
            // as is only checking on the file properies of /proc/<pid> directory
            // so we can't get the info needed only with stat(2)
            // and stat file doesn't have uid so we can't only use that
            // we need both
            stat(proc_path, s); 
            pi.uid = s -> st_uid;
            free(s);
            fclose(proc_stat);
        } 

    } 
    return pi;
}

void print_process_info(struct process_info pi){
    printf("pid=%d file_name=%s status=%c uid=%d ppid=%d\n", 
            pi.pid, pi.process_name, pi.status, pi.uid, pi.ppid);
}

int main()
{
    pid_t pid = getpid();

    while (pid > 0) {
        struct process_info pi = get_process_info(pid);
        print_process_info(pi);

        if( strcmp("(sudo)" , pi.process_name) == 0 ) {
            // found sudo 
            struct process_info sudo_parent_info = get_process_info(pi.ppid);
            printf("user that ran sudo is uid=%d, from process: \n", 
                    sudo_parent_info.uid);
            print_process_info(sudo_parent_info);
            break;
        }
        pid = pi.ppid;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

example output:

```
pid=41769 file_name=(hello_sudoer.o) status=R uid=0 ppid=41749
pid=41749 file_name=(sudo) status=S uid=0 ppid=20078
user that ran sudo is uid=1000, from process: 
pid=20078 file_name=(bash) status=S uid=1000 ppid=5985
```

Comment: so that's an interesting idea I will have a play with it.

Answer (score 0):

On systems running systemd (or more precisely, [`systemd-logind`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-logind.html)), you can get the user that launched the current session using [`sd_pid_get_owner_uid`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_pid_get_owner_uid.html):

```
#include <systemd/sd-login.h>
…
uid_t user_id;
if (sd_pid_get_owner(0, &user_id) != 0)
  … /* handle error */
printf("UID: %ju\n", (uintmax_t) user_id);
```

You need to link with `-lsystemd`.

This ID will indicate the user that logged into the system. It will not work for processes that do not have a login session (e.g., system services), but in this case, arguably no logged-in user exists for that process anyway. If a user has privileges to launch new sessions or services, they can obscure their original login session, too.

Comment: I think that's a little problematic as the I'm looking for a solution that ideally works on any distro. Of course there is a chance I may need to do some work to support specific distros.